# How to group text in one row and calculate the time duration in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe like this,

```
ID    time       text
1   8:43:43 PM   one day
1   8:43:51 PM   this code
1   8:44:07 PM   will help
1   8:44:17 PM   someone.
2   8:45:56 AM   yes
2   8:46:09 AM   I'm feeling
2   8:46:25 AM   good.
```

I want to group the time column by ID and calculate the time duration. I know we can use `join` to concat text and group by each ID.

The final output will be,

```
ID   time-duration    text
1    34        one day this code will help someone.
2    29        yes I'm feeling good.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do

```
df.groupby('ID').agg({'time':np.ptp,'text':' '.join})
Out[49]:  
       time                                  text
ID                                               
1  00:00:34  one day this code will help someone.
2  00:00:29                 yes I'm feeling good.
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `GroupBy.agg` with [`named aggregations`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html#groupby-aggregation-with-relabeling) *(best practice from `pandas >= 0.25.0`)*

The advantage of named aggregations is that we aggregate and at the same time rename our column, see `time_duration` in output.

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

dfg = df.groupby('ID').agg(
    time_duration=('time', lambda x: x.max()-x.min()),
    text=('text', ' '.join)
).reset_index()
```

```
   ID time_duration                                  text
0   1      00:00:34  one day this code will help someone.
1   2      00:00:29                 yes I'm feeling good.
```

Answer (score 3):

Groupby and aggregation:

```
(df.groupby('ID', as_index=False)
   .agg({'time': lambda x: (x.max() - x.min()).total_seconds(),
         'text': ' '.join})
)
```

Output:

```
   ID  time                                  text
0   1  34.0  one day this code will help someone.
1   2  29.0                 yes I'm feeling good.
```